# How to use Tensorflow to implement an input delay neural network

Tags: tensorflow

I want to implement an input delay neural network, but I don't know how to realize the tap delay in the input part, as shown in the picture below.

[image: Network architecture]

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand.  Could you include more about the tab delay so I can read about it a bit more to understand what it is supposed to do?

Comment: By "input delay", do you mean "time-delay"?